# Date 14 days before current date

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a subscription program and I want to create a journey and send an email 14 days before the subscription program ends.

In order to do that I need to run a query to get only the customers whose subscription ends within 14 days only, so today I would only get the customers that have the subscription end date on the 7th of January 2020.

I looked everywhere but can't find anything similar that works.

```
    SELECT
    CustomerID,
    Emailaddress,
    SubscriptionTypeName,
    Firstname,
    Lastname,
    SubscriptionStartDate,
    SubscriptionEndDate,
    IsActive,
    SubscriberKey

    FROM [Currently Active]

    WHERE IsActive = 'true'

    AND
```

[image: market]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using the `DateDiff` function.

> This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the
>   specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate
>   and enddate.

In a nutshell, this function does the operation: enddate(SubscriptionEndDate in your case) *minus* startdate(today's date).

This would translate into the query:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    Emailaddress,
    SubscriptionTypeName,
    Firstname,
    Lastname,
    SubscriptionStartDate,
    SubscriptionEndDate,
    IsActive,
    SubscriberKey

    FROM [Currently Active]

    WHERE IsActive = 'true'
    AND 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,GetUTCDate(),SubscriptionEndDate) = -14
```

**Reference:**

- [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @Rachid. This was giving me the customers with the SubscriptionEndDate on the 4th of February so two weeks after the current date but instead of 14 I did -14 and it seems to work

Comment: Yeah indeed, didn't read correctly your requirements. I'll update the answer ^^

Answer (score 2):

Datediff works, but it's not [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162263/68443).  Plus, I always have to review the order of the parameters and second-guess myself on if the result should be positive or negative.

I've gotten into the habit of simply specify a range for handling the time portions with as few functions as possible.

```sql
SELECT
  ca.CustomerID
, ca.Emailaddress
, ca.SubscriptionTypeName
, ca.Firstname
, ca.Lastname
, ca.SubscriptionStartDate
, ca.SubscriptionEndDate
, ca.IsActive
, ca.SubscriberKey
FROM [Currently Active] ca
WHERE 
ca.IsActive = 1
AND ca.subscriptionEndDate >= convert(date, GetUTCDate()-14)
AND ca.subscriptionEndDate < convert(date, GetUTCDate()-13)
```

Converting the UTC Date to the *date* datatype simply resets the time part of the *datetime* to midnight.